# append() breaks select2 dropmenu

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, select, append

I'm using `Select2` Version: `3.4.5` by Igor Vaynberg and came across some issue that appeared in Firefox and IE when I use the jquery `append()` function. It works perfectly fine in Chrome. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<select class="select2 itemMenu">
    <option value="0">Item 0 ...</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.itemMenu').select2();
$('.itemMenu').append($("<option>").val(1).html('testing'));
```

Chrome (working):
[image]

Firefox & IE (broken):
[image]

Comment: itemMenu is just a class name, i noticed i had a typo in the example above but it's correct in my code as seen in the screenshots (testing is appended). i'll update the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a typo in your code.

Try this, I tested and it's working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.itemMenu').append($("<option>").val(1).html('testing'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4tsM/2/

Let us know if you still have an issue.
Good luck

Comment: hey, yeah there was a typo in the example code i posted above but it's not like that in my code so the same problem still occurs as you can see in my screenshots (testing is appended).

p.s. i just fixed the typo in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Seems that this happens if you call select2() before append() instead of vise-versa.